# Is it possible to present the list of resources from Google sheets - one below the other, in an email output using HTML code?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

Link to Gsheet (refer Cols G-H) - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eSP42EmcMOCf9PMYGXetAVGHKz4c567F1-AOEmZwVlY/edit?usp=sharing
I use HTML code in my Google Appscript to send automated emails. The appscript works well, but I was wondering if there's any workaround to present the list one below the other in HTML. In sheets, I have used TEXTJOIN+CHAR(10) to make a combined list. I prefer to have the same view in email output as well.
Below is the sample HTML that I am using:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <p>Here&#39;s the list of people from Column G&nbsp;</p>

            <p><?= level2names?></p>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Below is the appscript I am using:

```
function trial() {
  var name1 = 0;
  var email = 1;

  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlcode");

  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  
  var data = ws.getRange("G2:H" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data.forEach(function(row){
    emailTemp.level2names = row[name1];    
    
    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[email],
      "Trial Output!",
      "Your email doesnt support HTML",
      {name: "Vish", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
}
```

Expected output:
[image]

Current Output:
[image]

Comment: Where is `level2names` in the templated HTML coming from? I only see you set `emailTemp.bdayss` when generating the template.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out. Updated the code. It should be emailTemp.level2names instead. Coming from ColG in the sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Code.gs, replace all `\n` newline characters in `row[name1]` to `<br>`:

```js
data.forEach(function(row){
    // Add this line:
    row[name1] = row[name1].replace(/\n/g, "<br>")

    emailTemp.level2names = row[name1]; 

    var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    GmailApp.sendEmail(
      row[name1],
      "Trial Output!",
      "Your email doesnt support HTML",
      {name: "Vish", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
```

And change your scriptlet type to [force printing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets):

```
<!-- Add the ! character after the ? -->
<?!= level2names?>
```